# Java applets in browsers: plug-in not found

Tags: java, html, browser

I have a old website with a Java applet on it, and I'm switching it over to a more HTML5 model. So I replaced my old `<applet>` tags (which stopped working in Firefox anyway) with new `<object>` tags, like:

```
<object id="IFApplet" name="IFApplet" type="application/x-java-applet" height="250" width="800">
    <param name="code" value="IFApplet" /> <!-- not sure if I'm doing this correctly... -->
    <param name="archive" value="com.mywebsite.IFApplet />
    ...
</object>
```

Now when I try to use my applet with Firefox, Chrome or Opera, I get an error message saying something to the effect that I'm missing a plug-in to display my content. Then it asks me if I want to automatically download an appropriate plug-in, when I say yes, the browser tells me it can't find any plug-in. Even if I install Java manually (or re-install it), I still get the same browser error. It works okay in IE9.

Does anyone know how to get this to work in the other browsers? Or how to get it to work cross-browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't done this in a long time, but i used to have problems as well and they went away when i started using the deployment scripts provided by oracle (back then it was still sun i think).

here is an example they provide: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'http://path/to/applet',
                      code:'your.main.class',
                      archive:'some-file.jar',
                      width:710, height:540} ;
    var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
    var version = '1.6' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

an alternative would be to simply put the old  tag inside the newer object tag.